# Where can I find drivers for a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, inspiron

Where can I find drivers for my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS notebook? It is a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series.

I'm looking on the Dell website but can't find anything.

Does anyone know where I can find these drivers?

Comment: Once you install, MOST of the drivers should already be present, if not run the additional drivers tool.  open your dash, type in "additional drivers", and open that tool.  unlike with Windows, *most* device drivers are already present and available as open source in the kernel and in packages that may have been installed (if you selected install third party required packages and drivers during install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most of the drivers for you Ubuntu by typing these commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

for the Dell specific drivers you can have them with these commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.dell.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dell.list'
sudo apt update
```

You can also look in `Softwares and Updates` -> `Additional Drivers`